# Filtering data based on month

Tags: php, arrays

How can I filter the entries where `created_at` is in the month of May?

```
$data = [
    (object) [
        'name' => 'Gadget',
        'created_at' => '2017-05-01'
    ],
    (object) [
        'name' => 'Tiddlywink',
        'created_at' => '2018-03-01'
    ],
    (object) [
        'name' => 'Gizmo',
        'created_at' => '2018-05-27'
    ]
];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to show what you have tried etc in order for people to help. Also you should read "how do I ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_filter()`, and check if the `created_at` property is of the month May (the 5th month). We do that by using a DateTime object, and comparing the `format("m")` with 5 (`m` gives the month in a numeric value from 1-12).

`array_filter()` will keep the elements only where the return-value is true.

```
$may_values = array_filter($data, function($obj) {
    $date = new DateTime($obj->created_at);
    return $date->format("m") == 5;
});
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/JKm8I

Answer (score 3):

This should works:

```
$new_array = [];
foreach($data as $v){
    $date = date_parse($v->created_at);

    if($date['month'] == 5){
        $new_array[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Gadget"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(10) "2017-05-01"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Gizmo"
    ["created_at"]=>
    string(10) "2018-05-27"
  }
}
```

What `date_parse()` does: (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)

```
array(12) {
  ["year"]=>
  int(2017)
  ["month"]=>
  int(5)
  ["day"]=>
  int(1)
  ["hour"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["minute"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["second"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["fraction"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["warnings"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["error_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["is_localtime"]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b639200d82661acdae7372f1762b02893b75f49

Answer (score 1):

I'd say loop through the created_at values, and single out the month ---

```
  $checkVal = date(m, strtotime($data['created_at']));
    if($checkVal == 5)
    ...
```

5 would be the # for the month of the year you want.

Comment: `if($checkVal = 5)` is assigning the value 5, not comparing to it.